# Filter duplicate emails to trash (Outlook 2016)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm facing an issue where I'll get duplicates of the same email. Let me explain how it happens:

- I'm marked as a receiver of the email
- Our customer service's email is marked as a receiver of the email
- Our customer service's email redirects messages to me (so simply I wouldn't need to be on the receiver field separately, but it still happens quite often.
- I get the same email twice

Is there a way to make a filter that automatically deletes the other mail? I was thinking of checking if my address and the customer service address are both found in the receiver's field, it would filter the other mail to trash. But looking at the filtering tool, I'm not sure if I can even perform a check for both.

Comment: There's Clean Up Folders feature starting in Outlook 2013 and on. It'll clean up your conversations and possibly the duplicates if Outlook 2016 sees as being part of the same conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any suitable ways to automatically remove these kind of duplicates on the fly. You need to fix it using organizational methods: your customer service has to stop redirecting messages to you if you're one of the recipients.

Comment: Never actually thought of it this way around! Thanks for the advice. Since it seems like there is no real answer to what I was initially looking for, I'll mark this question answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools that will solve your problem.

There is a VBA script here that will solve your problem: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ol-lookfordups/